# WCF testing service where transaction doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, database-connection

I made windows forms application which uses database and now I am trying to make WCF application, where this Win FORM will be client, then I will host it using ISS, but I have problem with transactions. To wit

I added to my existing solution (where I have this winform as well) new project-> WCF Service Application

in service.svc I have :

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public void AddEmail(string str, Queue<string> checkBoxes)
        {



     Task.Run(() =>
            {
                SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=G:\\VisualStudio2012Projects\\WCF_Muszynski_Grossman\\WcfService1\\App_Data\\Database1.sdf");
                conn.Open();                    

                try { MailAddress a = new MailAddress(str); }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    return;
                }


                if (checkBoxes.Count() == 0)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    return;   //no groups were selected
                }
                SqlCeTransaction tx = null;
                try
                {
                    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                   // MessageBox.Show(conn.State.ToString());
                    tx = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.Transaction = tx;


                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Emails(Email) VALUES('{0}')",str);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int UniqueID;
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select UniqueID from Emails WHERE Email='{0}' ",str);
                    SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    dr.Read();
                    UniqueID = (int)dr["UniqueID"];
                    dr.Close();

                    while (checkBoxes.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Insert into Groups(ID,Grupa) VALUES({0},'{1}') ", UniqueID, checkBoxes.Dequeue());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch (SqlCeException ex)
                {

                    tx.Rollback();
                    conn.Close();
                    return;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                    conn.Close();
                    return;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show(string.Format("typ bledu {0}", ex.GetType().ToString()));

                    tx.Rollback();
                    conn.Close();
                    return;


                }
                conn.Close();
              return;  
            });
    return;
    }
```

in IService.cs :

```
[OperationContract]
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
        void AddEmail(string str, Queue<string> checkBoxes);
```

Of course when I try to do those things without transaction it works properly.
Of course my database is moved to WCFService now.
So I am very puzzled why thing which worked in WinForm doesn't work now in Service.
Could you tell me why is that and what should I do?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no and thats also problem :/

Comment: What happens if you step through the code?

Comment: @scheien i am testing this service using  iisexpress.exe , so i think i cannot debug it...

Comment: @scheien so could you help me?

Comment: Ok problem solved it was IISExpress.exe 's fault , because when you test your service you need to specify head,size,tail of your array, not only elements of this array...